# Android disturbance in ongoing call

Tags: android, telephony

I have create the aidl file `ITelephony.aidl` for ending the call. Now before the call should be ended, I need to generate the voice in ongoing call, so that the listener assumes that there is a problem in next work.
I have tried to solve this by myself in three ways:

1. Control the audio stream volume

   ```
   audioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, isMute);
   int index = rand.nextInt(5);    
   audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL,index,0);
   ```
2. Another way is using the setMute in telephonyService

   http://androidsourcecode.blogspot.in/2010/10/blocking-incoming-call-android.html
   but working in in 2.3
3. I have also  tried to implement using media player for start playing when the call is going on but no luck. 
   So if there is any other idea then please let me know.

Comment: I cannot understand what you're trying to achieve exactly.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have the same problem I had a while ago: With Android 2.3 aka Gingerbread it's no longer possible to use the ITelephony interface because the MODIFY_PHONE_STATE permission has been marked system only.

Details may be found [here](http://androtrash.blogspot.com/2010/12/gingerbread-and-modifyphonestate.html).